# jQuery Attribute Selector with "OR" operator possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to re-write the following selector using an "OR" operator or similar?

```
$("a[href$='avi'], a[href$='mov'], a[href$='mp4'], a[href$='m4v']")
```

Ideally something like:

```
$("a[href$='avi|mov|mp4|m4v']") // incorrect
```

to get a few more miles out of my keyboard. I have a [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rossc1/JtRuA/4/).

Comment: You could add your own regex selectors (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) but it probably isn't worth it for this.

Comment: Thanks. For the example given it's not worth it but elsewhere it is useful.

Comment: @T.J. I am away to *possibly* deploy this across a large web app. The example given is a simple and basic test case given for illustration purposes to avoid being a) verbose and b) like I want to  play jQuery code golf. Something like regex is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for commenting on the answer which was marked as correct, to me this is an interesting discussion point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by extending jQuery with James Padolseys [Regex Selector for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/). Pretty useful when you want to put regex into your selectors.

[Run this code in Test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EUzV/1/)

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ?
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}

$("a[href$='avi'], a[href$='mov'], a[href$='mp4'], a[href$='m4v']")
    .addClass("select");


$('a:regex(href,avi|mov|mp4|m4v)').addClass("betterSelect");
```

Comment: @Ross: Be aware that while *really really cool*, this moves the filtering into the JavaScript layer, even on browsers that could support the series of comma-separated attribute-ends-with selectors directly in `querySelectorAll` (which is lots of them these days), impacting performance. Plus, note that Padolsey's stuff calls `jQuery(elem)` on **every** element that matches the tag name. Every call to `jQuery()` involves several function calls and some memory allocation. So it's fantastic stuff and very cool, but keep an eye out for performance impacts.

Answer (score 3):

No, CSS doesn't have this (it would be in the [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) area) nor does jQuery add it (see the ["attribute ends with" docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)).

You could, of course, give yourself a utility function to do it if you don't mind not being able to match the `|` character, something *vaguely* like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.attrEndsWith = attrEndsWith;
    function attrEndsWith(tag, attr, list) {
        return $(tag + "[" + attr + "$='" + list.split("|").join("'], " + tag + "[" + attr + "$='") + "']");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and used so:

```
$.attrEndsWith("a", "href", "avi|mov|mp4|m4v");
```

This is untested, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").filter(function(){ return /(avi|mov|mp4|m4v)$/i.test($(this).attr('href')); }).addClass('betterSelect');
```

Not really the answer you were looking for, but maybe it will help.

Comment: That will put the filtering in the JavaScript layer, even on browsers that could support the series of comma-separated attribute-ends-with selectors directly in `querySelectorAll` (which is a fair number of them these days), impacting performance. If performance isn't an issue, it's fine, but... (Also, there's absolutely no reason to do `$(this).attr('href')` and all the memory allocation and function calls that entails; `this.href` is universally supported.)